# VBA Workbook Save As

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping to save my new csv file sheet1 as "CSV123" but somehow the sheet name is always changed to filename after I save and close the file.

I am not sure why the .Sheets(1).Name = "CSV123" is registered when I use F8 to check but does not register after I close the workbook.

```
Sub Save_as_CSV()

    Dim Newbook As Workbook
    Dim filename As String
    Dim answer As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    answer = InputBox("Please enter the file name for save", "CSV File Name")
    If answer <> "" Then
        filename = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & answer & ".csv"
        Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
        shcsv.Copy before:=Newbook.Sheets(1)
        With Newbook
            .Sheets(1).Rows("1:3").Delete
            .SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=Excel.xlCSV
            .Sheets(1).Name = "CSV123"
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
    Else
    Exit Sub
    End If
     MsgBox "The CSV is exported to the same directory as this file."

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There are no sheet names in a CSV file  - by default Excel uses the file name for the sheet name.

Comment: If you want to preserve the sheet name, you would have to save it to another format like .xlsx (xlOpenXMLWorkbook).